# Can you give me an example of function $f$'s improper integral converges but $f\cdot f$'s integral doesn't converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

Could you provide me with an example: a function $f$ is a positive continuous function, and the integral of $f$ from $a$ to positive infinity converges, but the integral of the square of $f$ from a to positive infinity does not converge.

Comment: $x^{- {1 \over 2}}$.